# Windows modify text without creating new file

Tags: text, replace

I have a 1TB file that needs to be modified with a simple change: Either delete the first line or prepend a few characters to the file. Because of space limitations, I cannot use commands that redirect to a new file or use editors that load the entire file into memory.

What is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT: The best tool I've found thus far is FART http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/ but my file is encoded in UCS-2 and this tool doesn't seem to support it

Comment: I encountered this problem as well. I would really want to edit a file without having to make a new one because my files are HUGE. Many thanks to whoever providing some insight on this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with some relatively straightforward C code (or C++, or probably even Python or perl or whatever). However, there would be no backup, so if it doesn't go right... well, how important is this file?

The idea for the insert case would be to use `ftruncate()` to extend the size of the file to include the space for the new bits, then working from the end of the file to the start (to avoid overwriting any of the existing data), read a block and write it back out offset by the correct amount. Then write the new data at the front.

The deletion case would work by finding the first byte past what you want to delete, and starting there, read blocks and write them back offset back towards the front of the file by the proper amount, and then at the end, `ftruncate()` the extra bytes off the end of the file.

These are obviously not safe operations if they are interrupted for any reason, or if the code to perform them has not been well tested before hand - but it can be done. Buying the additional storage to make it possible to retain the original file while writing out the new one would probably be a considerably better investment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this with any mainstream operating system / file system, because they do not support "prepend to beginning of file" or "remove from beginning of file" operations, only "append to end of file" and "truncate file". Any solution will require reading the whole file in to memory and writing it back out with the desired changes.